# How to properly paint content on a wxScrolledWindow?

Tags: c++, user-interface, scrollbar, wxwidgets

I am creating an animation timeline widget using wxWidgets.
The widget consist of a wxFrame with a wxScrolledWindow child:
[image]

I want to support horizontal zooming by changing the timeline window virtual size when the user rolls mouse middle button.
Zooming without scrolling works well. But when i start scrolling(forward and backward) things get messed up.

So to troubleshoot I decided to do a simple test:
Draw a line from the window top left corner to the bottom right corner. And the test fails!

Without scrolling -> Test pass
[image]

Zoom then scroll to right -> Test fails
[image]

Scroll back to left -> Test also fails
[image]

I have no idea of whats going on. **Here my CPP code**:
**In .H**:

```
class AnimationFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    AnimationFrame();

private:
    void onTimelineMouseWheel(wxMouseEvent& ev);
    void onTimelinePaint(wxPaintEvent& ev);

    // The scrolled window.
    wxScrolledWindow* m_timelineWindow;
};
```

**In .CPP**:

```
AnimationFrame::AnimationFrame()
{
    assert(wxXmlResource::Get()->LoadFrame(this, NULL, "AnimationFrame"));

    m_timelineWindow = (wxScrolledWindow*)wxWindow::FindWindowByName("TimelineScrolledWindow", this);
    assert(m_timelineWindow);

    wxPanel* headerPanel = (wxPanel*)wxWindow::FindWindowByName("HeaderPanel", this);
    assert(headerPanel);

    // Adjust panel sizes.
    {
        headerPanel->SetMaxSize(wxSize(headerPanel->GetMaxSize().x, 40));
        m_timelineWindow->SetMaxSize(wxSize(m_timelineWindow->GetMaxSize().x, 100));
        this->SetMinSize(wxSize(this->GetSize().x, 250));
        this->SetSize(wxSize(this->GetSize().x, 250));
        this->SetMaxSize(wxSize(this->GetSize().x, 250));
    }

    // Timeline events from the scrolled window.
    m_timelineWindow->Bind(wxEVT_MOUSEWHEEL, &AnimationFrame::onTimelineMouseWheel, this);
    m_timelineWindow->Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, std::bind(&AnimationFrame::onTimelinePaint, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}


void AnimationFrame::onTimelineMouseWheel(wxMouseEvent& ev)
{
    static const nbFloat32 scrollIntensity = 1.20f;
    const nbFloat32 delta = scrollIntensity * (nbFloat32)(ev.GetWheelRotation() / ev.GetWheelDelta());

    const nbFloat32 sizeFactor = delta >= 0.0 ? delta : 1.0f / -delta;

    const wxSize currentVirtualSize = m_timelineWindow->GetVirtualSize();
    wxSize targetVirtualSize = wxSize((nbUint32)((nbFloat32)currentVirtualSize.x * sizeFactor), currentVirtualSize.y);
    targetVirtualSize.x = std::min(targetVirtualSize.x, 5000);
    targetVirtualSize.x = std::max(targetVirtualSize.x, m_timelineWindow->GetSize().x);

    m_timelineWindow->SetVirtualSize(targetVirtualSize);

    this->Refresh();
}


void AnimationFrame::onTimelinePaint(wxPaintEvent& ev)
{
    // Init the DC.
    wxPaintDC dc(m_timelineWindow);
    PrepareDC(dc);// from the scrolling sample. Doesnt seems to do anything.

    /*
    wxFont font(12, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_NORMAL);
    dc.SetFont(font);
    dc.SetBackgroundMode(wxTRANSPARENT);
    dc.SetTextForeground(*wxBLACK);
    dc.SetTextBackground(*wxWHITE);
    */

    // Now draw line.
    dc.DrawLine(wxPoint(0, 0), wxPoint(m_timelineWindow->GetSize().x, m_timelineWindow->GetSize().y));
}
```

**Addional information**:
As you certainly realised the widget is loaded from CPP using the XRC format. Here the generated code from wxFormBuilder for the widget.
XRC: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak_u4fVrMHMkrTe59Fuo4X2b-fRO?e=2Z0lw0
CPP: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak_u4fVrMHMkrTi_8w5UIkwFTl9t?e=BZBlLs

Comment: I presume it is on Windows with wxWidgets-3.2.1?

Comment: Handing a window that can scroll and zoom at the same time is a surprisingly complex problem. I wrote about one way to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318496/c-zoom-image-at-specific-location-centered/67320402#67320402).

Comment: @NewPagofi trying it thank you !!

Comment: The zooming works but there is no scrollbar

Comment: @Igor I use wxWidgets 3.1.5 on Windows  :). I can upgrade to 3.2.1 if necessary.